# SP 2013 MP > Correct syntax - Is this right?

Tags: 2013, master-page, css, cssregistration

I need to register 3 different CSS that are in the 15 hive in the masterpage. I have it in the following format and I checked the link thru IE address bar and they seems to resolve. Why then it's not being effective when I apply the masterpage?

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration  ID="Brand1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_layouts/15/brand/brand.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration  ID="Brand2" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_layouts/15/branding/HidePT.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration  ID="Brand3" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_layouts/15/branding/TitleBGColor.css%>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```

Comment: I also tried following way but still no help. I can drop the css using cewp and it works.<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="Brand4" Name="/_layouts/15/branding/WPTitleColor.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/> . Can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following format helps.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" ID="CssRegistration1" Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/style.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css"/>-->
```

Source: http://yakovenkomax.com/cssregistration-and-scriptlink-done-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<link href="indigo_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```

Look at [this blog post](https://samanalie.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/applying-custom-styles-to-page-layouts-in-sharepoint-2013/) about "Applying Custom Styles to Page Layouts in SharePoint 2013" it can be directly applied to a masterpage.